# Use of undeclared crate or module in my project

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I've been struggling for hours with an error in Rust and can't seem to resolve it.

Here's how my project is structured:

```
├── Cargo.toml
└── src/
    ├── main.rs
    └── controllers/
        └── user_controller.rs
```

In main.rs I have the following:

`use controllers::user_controller;`

However, when I try to run my project, I get the error message here:
[Error in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iakSD.png)

Also in VS Code
[Error in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qOrW.png)

What am I doing wrong?

I tried already every possible solution, but nothing seems really to help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rust cannot find module even though the file is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67958566/rust-cannot-find-module-even-though-the-file-is-present)

Comment: No, unfortunately, it doesn't really help. Their files are in the same directory, but mine are in their own

Comment: Oh. well for starters you need a `lib.rs`

Comment: @BallpointBen what? no you don't

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `user_controller.rs` is nested in the `controllers` module, it is inaccessible to `main.rs`. Therefore, you need to make the `user_controller` module accessible.

You can either:

Create a `controllers.rs` file (`controllers/mod.rs` in legacy projects) in the `src` directory which contains the following:

```
pub mod user_controller;
```

This declares the public module `user_controller`. You can then use the module `controllers` and `controllers::user_controller` from `main.rs`.

**Alternatively,** in `main.rs`, declare the module `controllers` and include the submodule `user_controller` :

```
mod controllers {
    pub mod user_controller;
}
```

Comment: It helped! Thank you!
But now yet one tiny problem. 
If I try to access a new file in a new folder. 
```/src/dal/user_db.rs``` 
from my 
```/src/controllers/user_controller.rs```? 
I get a pretty similar problem.
in 

```/src/controllers/user_controller.rs```  

this one doesn't work 

```mod dal
{
    pub mod user_db;
}```

Comment: @TimoSchmidt there are two parts to Rust modules: how you declare them and how you use them. In that case you would *declare* the module by putting `mod dal { pub mod user_db; }` in `main.rs`, then you would *use* that declared module from `user_controller.rs` by importing with `use crate::dal::user_db;` or similar.

Comment: I encourage you to find a nice blog or tutorial about Rust's module system since its not quite like other languages.

Comment: unresolved import `crate::dal`
could not find `dal` in the crate 

Yeah, I also noticed how cool and different RUST is. Sorry for being too intrusive. But I literally found nothing and Stackover is my last resort:)

Comment: @TimoSchmidt I think you missed the part about putting `mod dal { ... }` in `main.rs`, because `use crate::...` will look for modules in the crate root (which for normal binaries will be `main.rs`).

Comment: @kmdreko
Oh yeah! You are right! Thank you again. The last question: should I put every module in main.rs if i wish to access them from other modules? For instance: If i wish to access a func in ```scr/a/a.rs```   from ```scr/b/b.rs```    i should also include mod a {...} in ```main.rs```?

Comment: @TimoSchmidt all top-level modules will somehow need to be declared in `main.rs`, yes